# How to write xpath for tag named onclick within selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, onclick

I'm trying to click a tab which is clickable on application menu but once i try to capture that web element through xpath it's not working and getting "unable to find element" error.

HTML expression is the following:

```
td width="132" height="37" align=center class="passive" id="2" style="CURSOR: hand" onclick="submit2(2)" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1"
```

xpath is not working for this click action.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@onclick='submit2(2)']")).click();
```

Comment: Instead of providing a handcrafted HTML update the question with the actual HTML and the error stack trace

Comment: question is clear

Comment: You have an ID, why not use that? Have you tried a wait? Have you made sure that the element is not inside an `IFRAME`? Update your question with the different attempts to solve the problem and post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the `table` in full and with making an assumption that perhaps the initial html is slightly wrong. With the following html;

```
  <width="132" height="37" align=center class="passive" id="2" style="CURSOR: hand" onclick="submit2(2)" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
```

I'm able to use the this xpath to locate the element, and providing that it's unique enough not to mistake it to be another element with the same `onclick` value, this could do the trick.

```
//*[@onclick='submit2(2)']
```

However, I was unable to create a dummy table with the following html that was valid. Feel free to edit your original post with the surrounding html and I'll readjust as appropriate :)